# If I @ a user not in the post, will that user be notified?

Tags: support

I posted a question and later found a comment related to my question in another post, so I'd like to invite the comment-maker to say more in my post. So if I @ that user, will he/she be notified?

Comment: If there is something not addressed in [the FAQ on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/2509) please edit let us know.

Comment: Thanks, it is answered in a comment in your link.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a "Hey @poster" comment on a post they've been on; just reply directly to their comment. you can't "ping" people that are have never touched a question (because it would be annoying and lead to lots of false positives if you were to "@John" and notify all Johns on the site).

Also, @user never works in questions/answers, only comments. Questions/answers aren't directed at specific users.